# error navigator.network.connection doesn't work, states return anything

Tags: plugins, network-connection

I have a problem with the plugin: navigator.network.connection.
I've uploaded the new version and I followed all instructions to use it correctly.
The code is: 
HTML
<--a href="javascript:void(0);" data-role="button" class="btn swatch-8" onclick="loggati()">LOGIN<--/a>

JQUERY

```
function loggati(){ 
       if(isOnline()==true){
          alert("OK");
        }
     }

    function isOnline() {
        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
```

`if(states[networkState]=='No network connection'){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}`

If I try to print something after the instruction  states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';, the alert will not print.
The code hangs on that instruction.
If I try to print "states[Connection.UNKNOWN]", the code hangs.
Anyone know what the problem is?
Write I the code correctly?
I can't find anything on internet.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.
This plugin doesn't work with phonegap.
It's necessary to do an apk or a ipa to test it.